# My neural network classifier reports "Unexpected CURL error"

Tags: r, neural-network

While defining my classifier, the following error message appears, no idea what to do with CURL error and installed R package bit64, but not moving forward what should I do with this:

```
classifier = h2o.deeplearning(y = 'Exited',
                          training_frame = as.h2o(training_set),
                          activation = 'Rectifier',
                          hidden = c(6,6),
                          epochs = 100,
                          train_samples_per_iteration = -2)
```

This is the error:

> Error in .h2o.doSafeREST(h2oRestApiVersion = h2oRestApiVersion,
>   urlSuffix = urlSuffix,  :    Unexpected CURL error: couldn't open file
>   "C:/Users/FelhasznĂˇlĂł/AppData/Local/Temp/RtmpInvPFf/file25246dec7784.csv"

In addition: Warning message:

> In use.package("data.table") :   data.table cannot be used without R
>   package bit64 version 0.9.7 or higher.  Please upgrade to take
>   advantage of data.table speedups.

Answer (score 2):

Try to Install bit 64 RStudio from a different repertory

```
install.packages('bit64', repos = "https://cran.rstudio.com")
```

Happy Helping!!

Answer (score 1):

1. install.packages ('h2o')
2. install.packages ('bit64')
3. install.packages ('data.table')
4. data.table :: update.dev.pkg ()
5. updated my JDK java;
6. go to program files, java and delete the old java folder;
7. restart my computer.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the warning message, I think it's some problem at H2O. I updated the R version and the `data.table` and the warning still rising.

`data.table` version:

```
> packageVersion("data.table")
[1] ‘1.12.8’
```

My R version:

```
> R.version
platform       x86_64-apple-darwin15.6.0   
arch           x86_64                      
os             darwin15.6.0                
system         x86_64, darwin15.6.0        
status                                     
major          3                           
minor          6.3                         
year           2020                        
month          02                          
day            29                          
svn rev        77875                       
language       R                           
version.string R version 3.6.3 (2020-02-29)
nickname       Holding the Windsock
```

Comment: still after initialising bit64 package I have the same problem as well, with the same R version as well. What could that be, any idea? Many thanks, anyway